# Hyperledger: Composer business network installation error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Please help me to correct the error or tell me where to go for help.

When I start Fabric network, all looks fine. But when I try to install a business network with `composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile innodata-network@0.0.1.bna` I see an error:

[image]

Then I start looking at the logs of peer1 (second peer of Org2) and see such errors:

[image]

Logs of peer0 of Org1:
[image]

Logs of peer1 of Org1:
[image]

All sources here:
https://bitbucket.org/userVI/workchain

(I started Fabric with two yaml files: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml -f docker-compose-kafka.yaml up -d`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - "Failed to update ordering service endpoints" is likely due to the peer not being a leader and then receiving a command to update endpoints.  The bitbucket link shows nothing FYI.

I see you've modified the Dev environment sample createPeerAdminCard.sh script to suit your custom Fabric environment.

Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF this error is a failure of Composer to connect to the Fabric, one assumes all of the Fabric are started. It would appear the FQ names in your connection.json cannot resolve (and thus getting 'unavailable'). Can also be an issue associated with errors in the connection.json file, as you can imagine - in this case, with the CLI being unable to 'find' the Fabric containers to perform the network install - which brings me to Docker.

Docker containers run on the default bridge unless you specify something different - just saying. Your connection json file has dockerized names that each node in your Fabric network will need to resolve (eg Error 14: UNAVAILABLE).

You set the network within the docker compose .yaml file, etc - you can use docker inspect bridge and docker inspect  to check what containers are on which network etc.

The simplest way can be to have the FQ names resolved in an /etc/hosts file.

Also - have you tried to deploy the sample Fabric marbles chaincode to test your Fabric network? That would be a start https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/tree/v4.0/chaincode/src/marbles  - because that would verify the Fabric configuration is correct - before then configuring Composer to use that underlying Fabric.

Examples of Composer connection profiles are here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org and here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/connectionprofile.html

Comment: You said that the problem may be related to connection.json.
What have I done wrong? Here's the file:
https://bitbucket.org/aflcip/workchain/src/twoOrgChain/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/createPeerAdminCard.sh#lines-174

And all docker containers run normally until I try to install the business network.

Comment: Please look at the configuration files if you have the time. I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Access denied, can you paste without needing access control, thx